# <script> vs include in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

There are two ways that I can pull a javascript file into my template.  I could load them using  tags, and I can load them to be rendered as templates using Django's include tag.

Let's suppose that I want my javascript file to have access to the rendering context.  I am interested in naming posting ajax requests by referencing Django views using the reverse URL syntax {% url app.views.something %}.  I could easily hard code the URL into my JS files, by this makes them less reuseable.

What are the disadvantages of using include so that my urls render correctly?  Obviously this means a little more server-side work, but does it mean much else? The  tag also needs to request data from the server, so I doubt bandwidth is effected.  In essence, we are compressing two HTTP requests into one, which might actually have value, right?

Basically, I am looking for some Django best practices here. Is it appropriate to treat javascript files as templates? The documentation certainly days I can.  What do people do in practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend including your script source files in the standard `<script src="...">` manner, rather than using Django includes in a script tag. If you have multiple pages and you set caching headers, the browser will cache your scripts, so doing this definitely does save bandwidth. But ultimately I think it makes the most sense simply because it scales from small bits of JS up to full single-page apps, and there aren't really any disadvantages.

However, I think it's permissible to Javascript code in the template for the purposes of setting script parameters from values in your Django app. I would keep this very structured and localized. If you're using a master template to contain your boilerplate, that's a good place for it to live. Something like:

```
<script>
window.appParams = {
   view1Url: {% url app.views.something %},
   ...
}
</script>
```

No logic, just declarations.

Comment: hmmm, so I actually had this working beautifully.  I then made some changes related to dependency management (started using labJS), and it's no longer working.  I get a reference error:

Comment: I figured it out.  I lost the type attribute on my script tag

Comment: that was a lie. I lost a comma in the attribute definition